# What does "activated" DOI number mean?

Tags: online-publication, terminology, doi

I would like to know what the difference is between a DOI number and an activated DOI number. Additionally, I have a DOI number for an article of mine to be published in a TUBITAK journal in Turkey. After the actual publication, how long does it take the DOI number to be activated in the system?

Answer (score 8):

Because DOIs are often fairly predictable, and it's useful to have a single ID, many publishers assign them at an early stage of publication, well before the article is online. At this point, though, they're just a string of digits and don't really "become a DOI" until they're entered into the CrossRef system. I'm guessing this is what your publisher means by "activated".

When the publisher has submitted the metadata to CrossRef, the central system at `dx.doi.org` now knows that `doi:10.1234/5678.910` should resolve to `www.example.com/journal/article`, and the link can start working. Once the metadata is submitted, the DOI should be active fairly quickly - within a day, if not sooner, is my experience. However, some publishers delay submitting this metadata for a while even after the article is first published online in an 'early view' status or similar - I have no idea why, but I've seen it done.

Right now, there is nothing *technically* stopping publishers submitting the metadata before making the article live, but it's recommended to do so at or shortly after publication - so your DOI probably won't work until shortly after the article is posted online.

It would be nice for DOIs (especially for high-profile material) to be live at the moment of publication... and it may happen fairly soon. CrossRef recently held [a consultation](http://blog.crossref.org/2016/01/rfc-registering-content-before-online.html) on how best to do 'advance registration' of DOIs for unpublished material, and from comments I saw at the time I suspect the responses were fairly positive. This suggests we'll see a more robust approach to this in the near future, with DOIs that are live and resolve to something in advance of publication.

Comment: Has anything happened in the four interveining years? You might want to edit so that "recently" is replaced by "in 2016" in the last paragraph.

Comment: @Tommi it looks like they implemented it shortly after I wrote that reply, but I'm not sure quite how widespread pre-publication submission is now. Will update when I can figure it out.